# How to find a nearest number to average

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a sample like this where I want to find nearest value to average

city and weight are two separate columns

```
city  weight
A      23
A      22
A      45
A      97
B      34
B      22
B      23
C      76
C      23
C      23
```

I made a pivot and calculated the average of weight for A- which is 46.75

I need to find nearest number for A which will be 45 in this case

I think i need to use index and match, but how would i do it if have 17,000 rows with duplicate city names and different weight values?

Any help I would appreciate

so answer i am looking for is

```
Row Labels  Average of WEIGHT     nearest number
A                 46.75            45
B                 38.75            34
C                  23              23
```

Most similar answers are not using this set, please help me set up this formula i have tried:

```
INDEX(rawdata,MATCH(MIN(ABS(weight-$B2)),ABS(weight-$B2),0),2)
```

But it look at at whole array of weight from A-C. I oonly want it to look at values for A when it is comparing average of A,

And then weight of B when comparing average of B,

AND SO ON....

Please let me know what is wrong with my formula?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I did a poor job of reading your question, and just now realized that you clearly said you want to find the nearest `Weight` value to the average *among the values for the city* that the average was calculated for.  So I've updated the answer below.

It looks like you found [XOR LX's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25770461/use-of-index-match-to-find-absolute-closest-value) to a similar question, and you're pretty close to having it right.

XOR LX used a really neat little formula that gets around the limitations of `MATCH()` when searching through unordered data.  I'll explain how it works below.

In the data table shown below, I've calculated the averages with:

`=AVERAGEIF(A$2:A$11,A14,B$2:B$11)` (I get different answers than what you have shown above).

and the nearest `Weight` to the average with:

`=INDEX((A$2:A$11=A14)*(B$2:B$11),MATCH(TRUE,(A$2:A$11=A14)*ABS(B$2:B$11-B14)=MIN(IF(A$2:A$11=A14,ABS(B$2:B$11-B14))),0))`

Note that this is an array formula, so it must be entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]
**______________________________________________________________________________**

**How it works:**

`ABS(B$2:B$11-B14)` is an array of the differences between the average and all the numbers in the `Weight` list. And `(A$2:A$11=A14)` is an array of `True/False` values with `True` wherever the `City` equals `A14`.  Multiplying these two together gives an array of those differences in the positions corresponding to `City = A14`, with `0` everywhere else.

Next we want to find the minimum of those differences, but we have to create a slightly different array, because `MIN()` will return `0` if any `0's` are in the array.

`IF(A$2:A$11=A14,ABS(B$2:B$11-B14))` checks where `City = A14`, and returns the differences between `Weight` and the average for those positions, with `False` everywhere else.

Taking the minimum of that array, `MIN(IF(A$2:A$11=A14,ABS(B$2:B$11-B14)))` gives the smallest difference *for only those positions where* `City = A14`.

Now the equality `(A$2:A$11=A14)*ABS(B$2:B$11-B14)=MIN(IF(A$2:A$11=A14,ABS(B$2:B$11-B14)))` gives an array of `True/False` values with `True` in the position of the smallest difference for the current `City`.  `MATCH()` finds the position of the `True`, (which is the position of the nearest number) and that is fed to an `INDEX()` to return the actual value.

I hope this helps, and good luck.